# How to check SMB config on a Mac regarding connection to a FileServer

Tags: finder, network, permission, smb

We are using FileServer at our company but as an IT Member, I also have another account with admin privileges on the FileServer.

The admin account I am using to connect to the remote desktop to use ActiveDirectory and my normal AD Account to connect to the FileServer on the mac using the Finder.

So I am using the Finder option "Connect to server" -> "smb://ip_address/data" and afterwards is asking me for the user account. As written bevor, I am using for it my normal AD Account (the one without admin privileges) but somehow the session is build with the Admin Account and I can access all the Folders, etc.

This happens only when I connect to the Remote Desktop using the Microsoft Remote Desktop App for Mac at the first place and then to the FileServer using Finder.

If I reset my machine and do it in other way (fileserver first and then RDP) everything works as it should and I can only see 2 Folders like it should be.

I was looking for the smb.conf in /private/etc but I cannot find it. When I am using

```
sudo nano /etc/smb.conf
```

it opens a blank config file.

Do you have any clue why it does happen?

I would like to connect to the FileServer with my normal account and see only what I should see (2 Folders) and not the whole direction.